# Escaping nested double-quotes in a corrupted CSV file

Tags: awk, python, perl

I have a large corrupted "CSV" file with many nested double-quotes. For instance:

```
123,"I wonder how to escape "these" quotes with backslashes.",123,456
456,"I wonder how to escape "these" quotes with backslashes.",456,789
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

**Updated** with a real example:

```
n9sih438,4994fa72322,PMC,Rapid Identification of Malaria Vaccine Candidates Based on alpha-Helical Coiled Coil Protein Motif,10.1371/journal.pone.0000645,PMC1920550,17653272,cc-by,"To identify malaria antigens for vaccine development, we selected alpha-helical coiled coil domains of proteins predicted to be present in the parasite erythrocytic stage. The corresponding synthetic peptides are expected to mimic structurally "native" epitopes. Indeed the 95 chemically synthesized peptides were all specifically recognized by human immune sera, though at various prevalence. Peptide specific antibodies were obtained both by affinity-purification from malaria immune sera and by immunization of mice. These antibodies did not show significant cross reactions, i.e., they were specific for the original peptide, reacted with native parasite proteins in infected erythrocytes and several were active in inhibiting in vitro parasite growth. Circular dichroism studies indicated that the selected peptides assumed partial or high alpha-helical content. Thus, we demonstrate that the bioinformatics/chemical synthesis approach described here can lead to the rapid identification of molecules which target biologically active antibodies, thus identifying suitable vaccine candidates. This strategy can be, in principle, extended to vaccine discovery in a wide range of other pathogens.",2007-07-25
```

Nested double-quotes can occur in a "title" field (4th field) and in an "abstract" field (9th field).

Comment: Can your quoted fields also contain commas, e.g. `123,"I wonder, how to escape "these" quotes with backslashes.",123,456`?

Comment: @EdMorton Yes, quoted fields also contain commas.

Comment: Then does `123,"abc",456,"def",789` mean 5 fields (`123` and `"abc"` and `456` and `"def"` and `789`) or 3 fields (`123` and `"abc",456,"def"` and `789`)? How do you know? Do you only have 1 specific field per line that can contain nested quotes or can there be multiple such fields on a line?

Comment: @EdMorton `"abc",456,"def"` is one field. I have two specific fields per line that can contain nested quotes.

Comment: OK but how do you KNOW? I mean how can we write a program to make that determination. There's nothing in your question right now that'd tell us how to do so. If you only have 2 specific fields per line that can contain nested quotes maybe there's something about those 2 fields position in the line or characteristics that'd let us identify them. Please [edit] your question to include a more truly representative example that includes 2 such fields per line and include commas within the quoted fields and other quoted fields before/after them (i.e. the worst cases) and tell us how to parse them.

Comment: Don't just post 1 line under "updated example", especially with no associated expected output. [edit] your existing example to show a few lines (around 5) of **minimal** sample input/output that's truly **representative** of your real data (e.g. we don't need/want to see fields that contain 20+ words). If you post a MCVE with concise, testable sample input and expected output then we can help you, otherwise you're going to end up with something that kinda/sorta works for the specific input you posted but then fails now or later when run on your real data.

Comment: This is an interesting problem, I (and am sure others) would like to help you with it but so far there's just not enough information in your question to really do so. If some fields are always integers, include that info. If some are always a specific date format, include that too, etc. Any information that'll let us identify the fields you want worked on separate from the other fields will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I need some time to properly update my example.

Comment: A quoted field is required in CSV where a field contains comma, newline or quote. Quote inside a field is quoted by repetition, **not** backslash.  A possible partial solution is that a lone quote not adjacent to a comma or the start/end of a line should be repeated. That might fix 90% of your cases, and be the basis for a more refined version. In addition, if your data really has 10 fields and only field 9 is a string field, the problem is deterministic and easy to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a sample input file based on each line being 10 fields with fields 4 and 9 possibly quoted:

```
$ cat file
n9sih438,4994fa72322,PMC,here is an unquoted string,10.1371/journal.pone.0000645,PMC1920550,17653272,cc-by,here is an unquoted string,2007-07-25
n9sih438,4994fa72322,PMC,"here is a,",string,","within,", quotes.",10.1371/journal.pone.0000645,PMC1920550,17653272,cc-by,here is an unquoted string,2007-07-25
n9sih438,4994fa72322,PMC,here is an unquoted string,10.1371/journal.pone.0000645,PMC1920550,17653272,cc-by,"here is a,",string,","within,", quotes.",2007-07-25
n9sih438,4994fa72322,PMC,"here is a,",string,","within,", quotes.",10.1371/journal.pone.0000645,PMC1920550,17653272,cc-by,"here is a,",string,","within,", quotes.",2007-07-25
```

and then wrote this script (using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()`) to identify which type of input line each is and then modify the quoted field(s) accordingly:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{
    # The 4th and 9th fields may or may not be quoted so we are looking
    # for one of these patterns of fields:
    #
    #    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10           - type A
    #    1,2,3,"4",5,6,7,8,9,10         - type B
    #    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,"9",10         - type C
    #    1,2,3,"4",5,6,7,8,"9",10       - type D
    #
    # If we can determine which type of record we have then we can
    # identify the fields.

    delete f
    if ( match($0,/^(([^",]+,){9}[^",]+)$/,a) ) {
        type = "A"
        split(a[0],f)
    }
    else if ( match($0,/^(([^",]+,){3})(".*"),(([^",]+,){5}[^",]+)$/,a) ) {
        type = "B"
        split(a[1],f)
        f[4] = a[3]
        split(a[4],tmp)
        for (i in tmp) {
            f[4+i] = tmp[i]
        }
    }
    else if ( match($0,/^(([^",]+,){8})(".*"),([^",]+)$/,a) ) {
        type = "C"
        split(a[1],f)
        f[9] = a[3]
        f[10] = a[4]
    }
    else if ( match($0,/^(([^",]+,){3})(".*"),(([^",]+,){4})(".*"),([^",]+)$/,a) ) {
        type = "D"
        split(a[1],f)
        f[4] = a[3]
        split(a[4],tmp)
        for (i in tmp) {
            f[4+i] = tmp[i]
        }
        f[9] = a[6]
        f[10] = a[7]
    }
    else {
        type = "Unknown"
        split($0,f)
        printf "Warning, could not classify file \"%s\", line %d: %s\n", FILENAME, FNR, $0 | "cat>&2"
    }

    # Uncomment the following lines to see what the above is doing:
    #print ORS "################" ORS "Type " type ":\t" $0
    #for (i=1; i in f; i++) {
        #print i, "<" f[i] ">"
    #}

    gsub(/^"|"$/,"",f[4])
    gsub(/"/,"\"\"",f[4])
    f[4] = "\"" f[4] "\""

    gsub(/^"|"$/,"",f[9])
    gsub(/"/,"\"\"",f[9])
    f[9] = "\"" f[9] "\""

    $0 = ""
    for (i in f) {
        $i = f[i]
    }
    print
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
n9sih438,4994fa72322,PMC,"here is an unquoted string",10.1371/journal.pone.0000645,PMC1920550,17653272,cc-by,"here is an unquoted string",2007-07-25
n9sih438,4994fa72322,PMC,"here is a,"",string,"",""within,"", quotes.",10.1371/journal.pone.0000645,PMC1920550,17653272,cc-by,"here is an unquoted string",2007-07-25
n9sih438,4994fa72322,PMC,"here is an unquoted string",10.1371/journal.pone.0000645,PMC1920550,17653272,cc-by,"here is a,"",string,"",""within,"", quotes.",2007-07-25
n9sih438,4994fa72322,PMC,"here is a,"",string,"",""within,"", quotes.",10.1371/journal.pone.0000645,PMC1920550,17653272,cc-by,"here is a,"",string,"",""within,"", quotes.",2007-07-25
```

The output always quotes the 2 fields that might be quoted in the input - if you don't like that it's an easy tweak left as an exercise. I also used the more traditional way of "escaping" a double quote in a CSV which is to double it up. Again a trivial change if you prefer `\"` over `""`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk for more info on using awk on CSVs and CSV "standards".

Comment: Thanks, I learned a lot.